# when i click on back how can i navigate to another view in phonegap

Tags: jquery, cordova, sencha-touch

**i have retrieved data from db and displayed in a list using phonegap
when i click on back button it should navigate to another list which 
i have done in sencha touch
how can i do this???**

```
function querySuccess(tx,result){
    $('#Allwordslist').empty();
    $.each(result.rows,function(index){
        var row = result.rows.item(index);

    $('#Allwordslist').append('<li><a href="#"><h3 class="ui-li-heading">'+row['Word']+'</h3><p class="ui-li-desc">'+row['Type_Of_Word']+'</p></a></li>');

    });
    $('#Allwordslist').listview();
}
```

Comment: Are you talking about the Back Button of the ST application ? Or the back button in Android. The first involves listening for the 'back' event in the list. The second refers to catching the OS event called when the hardware "back" button is pressed. Please clarify.